# How to make multiple POSTS without page reload (html, mysql)

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, post, input

I am making a page with multiple input fields

```
  <form>
    <input type=”text” name=”1”>
    <input type=”text” name=”2”>
    Etc
 </form>
```

It is very important that as the input box is left the data is written to the database, without a page reload.  For example i) if the browser were to close while only half the input boxes were complete I need the user to be able to load the page again with that data having been saved. Ii) The first inputs results will depend on the structure of later inputs in the page thus will need to be stored in a database.

Do I need to do something like this?

```
<form>
<input type=”text” name=”1”>
</form>

<form>
<input type=”text” name=”2”>
</form>
```

Can I use AJAX? How? What about Sockets.io? I am using node, and a mysql database for some background

Comment: if you want to make it real time then use socket otherwise you can use ajax. with node socket is the best option

Answer (score 0):

Ajax works well here.

This tells you all about it:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Then once you learn it, all you have to do is add handlers to capture certain events which in your case could be focusing events (as the cursor changes between text boxes) then the javascript code will load the script responsible for communicating with the database then that script will return a value back to the javascript code which javascript will use to determine the outcome shown on the screen.

Comment: I have had a look at this, is it really the easiest way to do it? Do you have any knowledge of if sockets would be better?